# Django Website on Godaddy Domain wont load without https://www

Tags: django

My django site cannot be loaded by just typing in example.com or https://example.com I have to fully type https://www.example.com

Does anyone know why this may be? I thought it might have to be related to the SSL certicate but that all seemed fine.

The domain is hosted with Godaddy and I am using Pythonanywhere.com to deploy my django site.

Comment: if django is running behind a web server like nginx or apache, then that behaviour you are describing could depend on the web server configuration i.e. the virtual host configuration.

Comment: Take a look at PythonAnywhere help page about that  https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/NakedDomains/